# Use provider method inside Widget's deactivate method

Tags: flutter

I'm very new to flutter and I've run into an error I haven't been able to solve for days,  I have a User Class that looks like this

```
    class User with ChangeNotifier{
      FirebaseAuth _auth;
      FirebaseUser _user;
      GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
      Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
    }
```

This class has a method to Sign the User out of the application, this method looks like the following:

```
  Future signOut() async {
    _auth.signOut();
    _googleSignIn.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }
```

I want this method to execute when I perform up navigation from one page to the previous one, so i use it inside the Widget's deactivate method:

```
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).signOut();
    super.deactivate();
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
E/flutter (32016): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: A User was used after being disposed.
E/flutter (32016): Once you have called dispose() on a User, it can no longer be used.
```

I would gladly appreciate any help or suggestion regarding this.. Thanks!!

Comment: did you try it in the void dispose() ?

Comment: @FloW yes, but i still que get the SignOut method to execute. i get the following error: Another exception was thrown: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

Comment: just to make things clear, you want to sign the user out when some route is popped?

Comment: @LoVe Yes inside my User class i have a variable that Holds a FirebaseUser instance, and in my register page i have a form to fill all the information related to that firebaseuser, so when i pop the register page i want to signout that FirebaseUser since he wont be completing the registration

Comment: then no need to use these methods, if you are pushing the register page from,say for example, the splash screen then you can await the push method to be executed and then you can sign him out safely without error,of course given that the user lives above all these widgets, tell me if it works for you to post an answer

Comment: @LoVe Worked like a charm! thanks! i didn't know i could await a navigator push. Please do post your answer so i can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use these methods, if you are pushing the register page from,say for example, the splash screen then you can await the push method to be executed and then you can sign him out safely without error,of course given that the user lives above all these widgets.